# Java/Ignite - Function of Try Block

Tags: java, ignite

I'm new to Java, so this may be obvious, but consider the following two blocks of code. Version A leaves the server spinning forever, but Version B spins up then terminates the server. What is the function of the try block here?

Version A:

```
import org.apache.ignite.Ignition;
import org.apache.ignite.Ignite;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Ignite ignite = Ignition.start();
        return;
    }
}
```

Version B:

```
import org.apache.ignite.Ignition;
import org.apache.ignite.Ignite;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try(Ignite ignite = Ignition.start())
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why isn't this equivalent to `{ Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(); }` as the resource destructor would be called when leaving scope?

Comment: GOOGLE SAYS THERE ARE NO DESTRUCTORS MIND BLOWN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignite  instance is declared in a try-with-resource statement, it will be closed regardless of whether the try statement completes normally.
For more details about this you can visit https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html